# How to enable page refresh when Ember model loaded in parent route has nested models passed to child routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

A parent route in an Ember app loads a model from the server. The model is an array with a series of fields, including a field that is itself an array containing the models for the child routes. The model array is displayed in the parent route as a list where each item, when clicked, links to the child route while passing the selected model to the child route.

However, since the child route doesn't load its model from the server but receives it from the parent route, refreshing the page (or sharing the URL) when on the child route yields an error. What is a good way of solving that problem?

[Here](http://jsbin.com/uCodEfi/28/watch?html,js,output) is a JSBin with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the model hook in your child Routes, and as you are using ember data, use the fixtureAdapter and the store.

An slightly modified JSBin http://jsbin.com/oSUZUvE/2#/documents/1/subdocument/2

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('documents', function(){
    this.resource('document', {path: ':document_id'}, function () {
      this.resource('subdocument', {path: 'subdocument/:subdocument_id'});
    });
  });
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('documents');
  }
});
App.DocumentsRoute =  Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
   return this.get('store').find('document');
  }
}); 
App.DocumentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.get('store').find('document',params.document_id);
  }
});
App.SubdocumentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.get('store').find('subdocument',params.subdocument_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was actually a little reluctant to use ember-data because of [this new way of structuring data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration) that seems temporary (correct me if I'm wrong). I would prefer to have one AJAX call returning docs with the embedded subdocs. Also, when I refresh the page, I would ideally like the app URL to stay where it is (e.g. when I refresh at '#/documents/6/subdocument/8', your app goes back to '#/documents' but I would like it to stay at '#/documents/6/subdocument/8'). Any hint about that?

Comment: Ember-data is on beta stage, I don't think the new way is going to change drastically

Comment: How are you refreshing page? if you are hitting ctrl+f5 or any other way that refresh js cached, you are re-initializing all the app and this force it to the initial state

Comment: I guess you are right. I guess the only way a refresh (by hitting ctrl+f5 for instance) can keep the app at the same non-initial state is if every part of the dynamic URL gets its model from a different call to the server.

Comment: Follow-up question: assuming you are using a RESTAdapter, how would you structure the payload for the above example?

Comment: With hasmany relations and sideloading childs with parents objects from the parent endpoint http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/ and read also https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration

Comment: Upon reading this, i realized i have a same kind of problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895209/ember-nested-child-route-loses-model-upon-route-refresh-reload , so did you get a chance to resolve this. If yes, do you think it could help me as per my problem.

Comment: Sorry but since '12 i'm not coding ember apps... I think ember has changes a lot but you can ask @YehudaKatz